# плагин для instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

Eсть необходимость подключить **instagram** к странице сайта, нашел простой плагин **jqinstapics** (http://projects.craftedpixelz.co.uk/jqinstapics/), который просто выгружает последние фотографии, то что мне и нужно, но никак не могу его подключить, токен и **ID** указывал тот, который мне выдавал сайт плагина(в конце сайта) может в самом **instagram** нужно какие то доступы прописывать или плагин мертвый? Вот моя страница, убрал все лишнее, оставил только [то, что нужно плагину](http://freehostblizz.tk/Nu/2.html)

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки, что jQuery не подключен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте консоль. На вашем сайте не подключён Jquery. Вот правильный путь для самой последней версии библиотеки:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
```

**UPD**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#instagram").jqinstapics({
          "user_id": "2541539321",
          "access_token": "2541539321.674061d.365cbbb574d4458284680ac81062541b",
          "count": 5
        });
});
```

Измените ваш скрипт как указано выше. У меня работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменял не помогло, причем я сейчас зашел в инстаграм в раздел управления приложениями и там стоит разрешение у этого плагина (ACCESS YOUR BASIC INFORMATION )

Comment: @Lex, обновил ответ

Comment: огромное спасибо! как всегда самое банальное не проверил...